# Optimize CSS Delivery External Link

Tags: css, google-pagespeed

I want to optimize my page speed. I have checked with this [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dealmecoupon.com%2F). I have solved js problems. But I didn't find any solution for external css like [THIS](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css) which I added from others source.

How can I resolve this css problems? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this css after download in your local and also with related fonts like

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

Answer (score 0):

to optimize your page speed more, minify your styles and put them into one file using build tools like grunt and gulp, but if you are not comfortable working with them just copy and paste or use some online tools like [shrinker](http://www.shrinker.ch/), it will do both operations for you. Also, consider moving down your style (if it links to a large file) and script tags to the bottom of the html file.